# Почему название "Стройка" находится выше блока, для которого прописаны свойства?

Tags: html, css, background, header

Почему название "Стройка" находится выше блока, для которого прописаны свойства? То есть фон блока красный, а название как будто в своем блоке выше и имеет белый цвет фона.

```css
* {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Стройка</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё нормально, всё на своих местах. Просто селектор `*` имеет больший приоритет, чем селектор по классу - он и перебивает своим цветом фона:

```css
* {
  /*background-color: #ffffff;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Стройка</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Всем большое Спасибо!!! Только начал что-то верстать, поэтому вопросы будут максимально простыми, возможно даже глупыми))

Comment: @G_M: прежде, чем задавать вопрос, воспользуйтесь поиском. Также, в процессе написания заголовка к вопросу, Вам предлагаются подходящие вопросы - может стоит сначала посмотреть их.

Comment: Очень трудно найти ответ на конкретный вопросы, с учетом, что я тут впервые. Также люди даже один и тот же вопрос задают по разному, поэтому проще самому задать, чем тратить время на поиск. Но, возможно, вы сможете меня переубедить, если покажете как правильно искать необходимую информацию.

Comment: @G_M: вот тут Вы не совсем правы. Искать было бы намного проще, если люди старались формулировать вопросы, добавляли бы малейшие детали и прикладывали код, а не картинки. Но, надеюсь, у Вас всё получится. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за дельные советы и адекватное общение, чего, к сожалению, сегодня не хватает. Буду стараться и развиваться.

Comment: @G_M: я свой первый вопрос здесь задал почти через год, после регистрации. Всё это время старался найти ответы, по-разному вбивая в поиск. Параллельно смотрел, как задают и оформляют вопросы и ответы.

Comment: Опять же получается, что для поиска ответа нужно потратить больше времени, чем задать свой вопрос, указав все нюансы. Я за 3 мин зарегистрировался, за 2 задал вопрос и, буквально, через 5 мин получил ответ.

Comment: @G_M: конечно, кому как удобно. Но, раньше поисковики сразу выдавали нужный полезный результат, а сейчас кучу мусора. Как Вы думаете, откуда этот мусор взялся? Эх...

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у тебя есть вот такой стиль:

```
* {
  background-color: #ffffff; //ВСЕМ БЛОКАМ БЕЛЫЙ ФОН, ЕСЛИ НЕ ЗАДАНО ИНОЕ
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Убери это и будет счастье)

Answer (score 0):

Вы указали для всех элементов белый фон:

```css
* {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Поэтому заголовок перекрывает верхнюю часть красной обёртки. В свою очередь оба блока занимают всю ширину экрана. 
Уберите белый фон:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```